# Surround test class with transaction and rollback

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-data, integration-testing

I wrote an integration test with multiple tests which based on each other. Therefore the test methods aren't independent and the exection order is enforced by `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` and naming convention.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AnIntegrationTest {
   @Test
   public void t001startProcess() {
       // ...
   }
   @Test
   public void t002addItem() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

The test keeps the created data in the H2 test database and subsequent tests will fail when executed in a test suite.

How can I souround the all tests of the class with a transaction and rollback all database modifications after all tests of the class were executed?

Comment: You cannot as each test is an individual tx. Maken tests methods dependend is a bad thing imho. It makes tests  brittle and hard to maintain.

Comment: @M.Deinum Really? Also without `@Transactional`? I need the dependency to minimize the test execution time.

Comment: When running without `@Transactional` there normal transactional demarcation in your program will take over. And if you thus do multiple calls you will have multiple tx, instead of a single tx for the `@Test` method. It is an integration test, the running speed shouldn't be a primary factor imho. Shouldn't it just be a single test? You could create a single `@Test` method and call the other 3 methods in there (and remove `@Test` from the other test methods). You still have the same assertions/tests but it is a single system/integration test.

Comment: `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AUTO_CONFIGURED)` instead of `@EnableTransactionManagement` seems fixing the issue.

Comment: `@EnableTransactionManagement` doesn't do anything on a test class, the autoconfigure one will replace the actual database with an H2 one which will be destroyed after the test. It doesn't actually do a rollback as that isn't possible because anything committed stays committed unless you do a deletee.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can't be the perfect solution to your requirement, but here is some help

If your requirement for integration test is to perform `SELECT/UPDATE` operation on the added rows, then you can do an `insert` query in the test class in the `@Before` annotated method and then `delete` query in the `@After` annotated method.

This will make sure that records are added and then deleted every time the test method is executed. But if you want the data updated in one test method to be present during the next test method execution, then this solution won't work

Example

```
Class ClassToBeTested {

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
      // write insert queries here
      }

      @Test
      public void method1() {
      // Integration test here
      }

      @Test
      public void method2() {
      // Integration test here
      }

      @After
      public void destroySetUp() {
      // write delete queries here
      }
}
```